# exec.Wait() with a modified Stdin waits indefinitely

Tags: go

I encounter a weird behavior with exec.Wait() with a modified Stdin.
I'm just modifying Stdin in order to be able to duplicate its content, count the amount of data… but that's not the problem here.

I've made this stripped down program just to demonstrate the strange behavior :

- with a modified Stdin, `cmd.Wait()` waits indefinitely… until I press "enter" or "^C"
- with an unmodified Stdin (uncomment the line `cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin`), the program processes to the end flawlessly.
- when I launch this program (with a modified Stdin) with Delve (`dlv debug`), the program processes to the end flawlessly !
- I also added a `time.Sleep` of 30 seconds between `cmd.Start()` and `cmd.Wait()`, and then attached the program to Delve (`dlv attach PID`). When I enter `continue`, `cmd.Wait()` waits indefinitely… until I press "enter" or "^C"

I tested these behaviours with go1.11 and go1.12

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

type Splitter struct {
    f  *os.File
    fd int
}

func NewSplitter(f *os.File) *Splitter {
    return &Splitter{f, int(f.Fd())}
}

func (s *Splitter) Close() error {
    return s.f.Close()
}

func (s *Splitter) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return s.f.Read(p)
}

func (s *Splitter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return s.f.Write(p)
}

func main() {
    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    cmd = exec.Command("cat", "foobarfile")
    cmd.Stdin = NewSplitter(os.Stdin)
    //cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = NewSplitter(os.Stdout)
    cmd.Stderr = NewSplitter(os.Stderr)
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.Wait()
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `Wait()` is blocking, that means `cat` is still running -- right? If you look at that copy of `cat` with `strace` or a similar tool, what operation is it blocking while trying to accomplish?

Comment: BTW, why are you passing stdin to a process that doesn't read from it at all? If it's a standin for something that *does* need to read content from the terminal or user, wouldn't it make more sense to select a standin that does the same as well?

Comment: Does it end if you close its stdin?

Comment: Does it work if you _not_ call `Fd()` in the `NewSplitter`? I'm asking because `Fd()` is not _that_ simple—for instance, it forces the `*os.File` it was called on into blocking mode; [see for yourself](https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go#L62).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : no, cat is no more running. Here it's a cat because it's easy to test, but it can be anything else, interactive or not (ssh, scp…).

Comment: @Adrian yes, it ends if I do os.Stdin.Close()…

Comment: @kostix: I tried not using Fd(), but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program duplicates the content as you asked. You can although try the commented part as well. And the comments are self - explanatory, I hope it explains your query.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // Execute cat command w/ arguments
    // cmd := exec.Command("cat", "hello.txt")

    // Execute cat command w/o arguments
    cmd := exec.Command("cat")

    // Attach STDOUT stream
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    // Attach STDIN stream
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    // Attach STDERR stream
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    // Spawn go-routine to copy os's stdin to command's stdin
    go io.Copy(stdin, os.Stdin)

    // Spawn go-routine to copy command's stdout to os's stdout
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)

    // Spawn go-routine to copy command's stderr to os's stderr
    go io.Copy(os.Stderr, stderr)

    // Run() under the hood calls Start() and Wait()
    cmd.Run()

    // Note: The PIPES above will be closed automatically after Wait sees the command exit.
    // A caller need only call Close to force the pipe to close sooner.
    log.Println("Command complete")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I played a bit with StdinPipe, but then I don't understand how I can count the amount of data going through the pipe. With the initial code, I could easily count in the Read and Write methods, with len(p)

Comment: In fact it was really easy, I just had to change the io.Copy of stdin to : `go io.Copy(stdin, NewSplitter(os.Stdin))`. Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the process file descriptors, which are normally `*os.File`, with other Go types. In order for stdin to act like a stream, the `os/exec` package needs to launch a goroutine to copy the data between the `io.Reader` and the process. This is documented in the [`os/exec`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/?tab=doc#Cmd) package:

```
// Otherwise, during the execution of the command a separate
// goroutine reads from Stdin and delivers that data to the command
// over a pipe. In this case, Wait does not complete until the goroutine
// stops copying, either because it has reached the end of Stdin
// (EOF or a read error) or because writing to the pipe returned an error.
```

If you look at the stack trace from your program, you'll see that it is waiting for the io goroutines to complete in `Wait()`:

```
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc000076000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/os/exec/exec.go:510 +0x125
main.main()
```

Because you are now in control of the data stream, it is up to you to close it as necessary. If Stdin is not necessary here, then don't assign it at all. If it is going to be used, then you must `Close()` it to have `Wait()` return.

Another option is to ensure that you *are* using an `*os.File`, which the easiest method is to use the [`StdinPipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/?tab=doc#Cmd.StdinPipe), [`StdoutPipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/?tab=doc#Cmd.StdoutPipe) and [`StderrPipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/?tab=doc#Cmd.StderrPipe) methods, which in turn use [`os.Pipe()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/?tab=doc#Pipe). This way ensures that the process is dealing only with `*os.File`, and not with other Go types.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Indeed it works well if i use os.Stdin.Close(). But I don't know when I have to close it, because the command can be anything, interactive or not, like ssh and scp… So I think I need to go with StdinPipe…

Comment: @Cyril: you know when you have to close it when you have nothing more to write to stdin; though it's still going to be easier to use `StdinPipe` when you can.